# Using MSAL to get tokens without using MSAL to sign in

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, dynamics-365

Portal capabilities for Dynamics 365 provides the ability to sign in using [Azure AD B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/portals/azure-ad-b2c). This is a feature of the product over which I have limited control, as far as I know, this is feature is implemented without MSAL.

Within the context of the portal I am attempting to use MSAL to acquire a token, `acquireTokenSilent`.

With a user signed into the portal - using the native features of the portal and not MSAL, e.g. `loginPopup` - using `acquireTokenSilent` results in `user_login_error:User login is required`.

Is this a scenario that MSAL actually supports? The ability to recognise the user is signed into Azure AD B2C but not via MSAL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, not supported.  The library expects a sign-in via the library.

Wonder what they would say if you posted an [issue in their repo](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues)?

Comment: We shall see https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/283

Comment: @jameswood were you able to get this to work. I see someone left a comment https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/283#issuecomment-404972801 but can't see any documentation

Comment: @Boomerang, no, I took a different approach to my problem in the end.

Comment: @jameswood Thanks. do you know if they ever implemented this

Comment: @Boomerang, no idea, just what is in the issue I raised.